# Jenkins to globally limit total number of concurrent running jobs

Tags: jenkins

is there a way to globally limit total number of concurrent running jobs?

I know that I can throttle number of concurrent runs per job/node, but I need a way to globally set this to apply on all jobs without the need to pass by each job and modify it

for example: total number of runs: 100 this means that no more than 100 job/build can be running concurrently

Answer (score 0):

The numbers of runs that can run concurrently on a Jenkins server is the number of available executers you currently have on the server. Therefore to limit the number of concurrent executions you can just limit the number of executers.
Each static node (Agent) including the master itself can be configured to have a specific number of executers - which is the number of jobs that can run concurrently on that agent, and in case you are using a cloud plugin for dynamically provisioning agents - almost all cloud plugins have built in support for limiting the number of provisioned instances and settings the number of executers each agent will have.

Therefore using the available executers you can control the total number of concurrent running jobs and limit their number as needed.